# Azure web app not accessible/stopped working

Tags: azure

I have a deployment slot on Azure. During debug of my debug slot it suddenly stopped working. I therefore stopped and started it again. Now I am not able to access it on the azure portal:

[image]

If I tried to navigate to the service from VS I get:

[image]

Starting and stopping is not working. And I cannot find anybody with this issue. I can't even delete it to recreate it, since the deployment slots has completely disappeared :/

Anybody have an idea of how to tackle this, e.g. through azure command prompt or powershell?

*Error Message in Azure*
When I try to publish I get the following:

> Web deployment task failed. (Could not connect to the remote computer ("AppServie-development.scm.azurewebsites.net") using the specified process ("Web Management Service") because the server did not respond. Make sure that the process ("Web Management Service") is started on the remote computer.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC.)    AppService  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets    4283

Comment: This is related to a transient outage. Nothing can be done to help here. The question should actually be closed/deleted. Sorry..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is related to a service outage. Not a programming question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

happened to all our services including DB connections just a short moment ago.  Now waiting for resolution from their side....

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/

it only mentioned global DNS issue, but I guess that means all services?...  anyway, I'm sitting duck here waiting my boss to shout at me

---

### 14:03

All our services are back online

we are not paying the support subscription so unofficially we are their second class customers...?

but anyway problem solved, a typical 1 hour experience as we have with Microsoft in most technical issues.... (personal opinion - not bad overall when running in a cloud)

Comment: Thanks, same! Here I go for long toilet trip.

Comment: Same issue here. Anybody knows what's going on?

Comment: This has been the second time in the past few days in the West Europe, I guess today's issue must be some how linked to the previous one

Comment: @LidaWeng okay, how big was it last time because I did not experience it on our development server? (big == time)

Comment: @JTIM https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/history/ .    We experienced the one noted on 09/09/2016 - roughly about 2 hours.

Comment: Please delete - this question isn't programming related, and there shouldn't be any answers posted.

Answer (score 2):

All our services went down as well due to connection issues with DBs

Comment: Please delete - this question isn't programming related, and there shouldn't be any answers posted.

Answer (score 1):

I am also following on Twitter on "#azure". Seems to be a problem that hits *a lot* of people right now. Also many of the bigger websites in North Europe seems to be super slow / down.

Seems to be only in North/West Europe.

Comment: We are in East US. Its affected our Database connections.

Answer (score 1):

News from : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/

DNS - Multi-Region

Last updated 5 minutes ago

Starting at 11:48 UTC 15 Sep, 2016 a subset of customers using DNS in multiple regions may experience difficulties connecting to their resources hosted in this region. This issue is also having knock-on impact on impact on multiple Azure services, including SQL Database, Virtual Machines, Visual Studio Team Services, and App Service \ Web Apps. Engineers are aware of this issue and are actively investigating. The next update will be provided in 60 minutes, or as events warrant.